# Algorithm to get unique combination of integers using multiplication

Tags: algorithm, combinations

I got bunch of 2s and 3s that i have to multiply together. Now i want to generate every unique combination of these numbers such that when these combination are multiplied does not exceed 10.

For example, I have something like this.

```
2*2*2*2*3*3*3
```

I can have following valid combination from above.

```
4*4*9*3
8*6*9
4*2*6*9
```

But the following combination are wrong. `16*3*9` and `4*4*27`.

Can somebody suggest an algorithm to do this?

Comment: A homework?  A contest?  Sounds a bit too artificial for a real-life problem.

Comment: For a projecteuler problem i was trying to solve :-). Got a bruteforce method, but i am not happy with that.

Comment: Because here one of the multiplicand exceeds 10.

Comment: ProjectEuler No 88. My idea is to get a number between k and 9k, find its prime factors (prime factors have to be lesser than 10) and then shuffle the 2s and 3s to get all the multiplication combination. Here is the link to the problem http://projecteuler.net/index.php?section=problems&id=88

Comment: I don't see how the answer to this question will help with #88, but good luck nonetheless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution can be built up recursively. Consider the input as a list of numbers such as [2,2,2,2,3,3,3]. Divide the list into a prefix (such as [2,2]) and the corresponding suffix ([2,2,3,3,3] in this case). Now multiple the entries in the prefix (and we get 4 in this example), and recursively solve the same problem for the suffix. Inserting the value from the multiplicity to the beginning of each of the solution for the suffix, we get the answer for the original problem.

In the following Python code, the recursive logic is defined in the function `collapse`, which finds all valid prefix (whose multiplicity is less than 10) and insert the multiplicity to all the results returned in collapsing the remaining data after cutting out the prefix (`collapse(d[prefix_len:])`).

```
a = [2,2,2,2,3,3,3]

def collapse(d):
    if len(d) > 0:
        for prefix_len in range(1, len(d) + 1):
            prefix = reduce(lambda x,y: x*y, d[:prefix_len], 1)
            if prefix > 10:
                break
            for suffix in collapse(d[prefix_len:]):
                yield [prefix] + suffix
    else:
        yield d

for i in collapse(a):
    print i
```

Output is

```
[2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3]
[2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 9]
[2, 2, 2, 2, 9, 3]
[2, 2, 2, 6, 3, 3]
[2, 2, 2, 6, 9]
[2, 2, 4, 3, 3, 3]
[2, 2, 4, 3, 9]
[2, 2, 4, 9, 3]
[2, 4, 2, 3, 3, 3]
[2, 4, 2, 3, 9]
[2, 4, 2, 9, 3]
[2, 4, 6, 3, 3]
[2, 4, 6, 9]
[2, 8, 3, 3, 3]
[2, 8, 3, 9]
[2, 8, 9, 3]
[4, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3]
[4, 2, 2, 3, 9]
[4, 2, 2, 9, 3]
[4, 2, 6, 3, 3]
[4, 2, 6, 9]
[4, 4, 3, 3, 3]
[4, 4, 3, 9]
[4, 4, 9, 3]
[8, 2, 3, 3, 3]
[8, 2, 3, 9]
[8, 2, 9, 3]
[8, 6, 3, 3]
[8, 6, 9]
```

Comment: That misses some valid combinations, such as `[8, 6, 9]`.  I think you want `for prefix_len in range(1, len(d) + 1):`.

Comment: This doesnot print all the combinations. eg: For list[2, 2, 3, 3], it doesnot print [6,6]

Comment: @matthew thanks for pointing this out. It's fixed. @chapprar I assumed the OP did not want the switch order of the numbers in the list, so [4,9] is valid while [6,6] is not. This is just my assumption.

Answer (score 2):

If order matters (i.e. 2*4*2 is not the same as 2*2*4) and you have to list them (i.e. "generate") then you should just do it all recursively.  In Scala:

```
def combine(who: List[Int], limit: Int=10): List[List[Int]] = who match {
  case x :: y :: more =>
    combine(y :: more, limit).map(x :: _) :::
    (if (x*y<limit) combine((x*y) :: more, limit) else Nil)
  case x :: Nil => List(who)
  case Nil => List()
}
```

You may not know Scala, so here's how the three cases work.  First case: list has at least two elements remaining.  Pick off the first element and add it to all possible later combinations.  Then, *if* you can merge the first and second elements, do so, and find all combinations of the list that starts with that.  Second case: trivial list with only one element; return that as the only thing in the list.  Third case: degenerate input (no values given); return an empty list.

(In Scala, `:::` concatenates two lists together, while `x :: list` sticks `x` on the front of `list`.  When you're matching, it goes the other way around: `case x :: stuff` is used if the list can be broken into an element `x` and the rest, `stuff`.  `Nil` is the empty list.)

Here it is in action:

```
scala> combine( List(2,2,2,2,3,3,3) )

res18: List[List[Int]] = List(List(2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3), List(2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 9),
  List(2, 2, 2, 2, 9, 3), List(2, 2, 2, 6, 3, 3), List(2, 2, 2, 6, 9),
  List(2, 2, 4, 3, 3, 3), List(2, 2, 4, 3, 9), List(2, 2, 4, 9, 3),
  List(2, 4, 2, 3, 3, 3), List(2, 4, 2, 3, 9), List(2, 4, 2, 9, 3), List(2, 4, 6, 3, 3),
  List(2, 4, 6, 9), List(2, 8, 3, 3, 3), List(2, 8, 3, 9), List(2, 8, 9, 3),
  List(4, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3), List(4, 2, 2, 3, 9), List(4, 2, 2, 9, 3), List(4, 2, 6, 3, 3),
  List(4, 2, 6, 9), List(4, 4, 3, 3, 3), List(4, 4, 3, 9), List(4, 4, 9, 3),
  List(8, 2, 3, 3, 3), List(8, 2, 3, 9), List(8, 2, 9, 3), List(8, 6, 3, 3), List(8, 6, 9))
```

---

Edit: if you just wanted to count them, you'd use a different type of recurrence.  Let `S(n)` be the number of combinations taken from the `n`th onwards, and let `L(n)` be the value of the `n`th item in your list.  Then

```
S(i) = S(i+1) +
       if (L(i)+L(i+1)<10) S(i+2) +
       if (L(i)+...+L(i+2)<10) S(i+3) +
       ....
```

So you start with the last item--only one possibility there--and work your way backwards in order using this formula.  (If this is what you're after, I'll write code that does it, but hopefully the algorithm is clear enough as is.)